# Hi, how to set the order of fields in measure drop down in pivot table in odoo?

Tags: odoo-10

I would like to set a specific order for the fields to appear in measure drop down in a pivot table.

Is it possible to alter the default order?

Comment: Yes but before that you need to past your copy of code and alter your question properly, Because in this question not able to understand what you want to do and in which things, Thanks